# Magento checkboxes disabled not working

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am trying to **disable** a **checkboxes** in magento. But It's not working.

```
        $fieldset->addField(
            'checkstatus', 'checkboxes', array('Select Status')
            'label' => $this->__(',
            'name' => 'checkstatus[]',
            'values' => $options,
            'checked' => $optionselected,
            'disabled'=> true,
            'readonly'=>true
            )
        );
```

Could you please help me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disabled` this will work for single checkbox for multiple checkbox you can add `'disabled' => array(//your values array),`

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'checkstatus', 'checkboxes', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Select Status'),
            'name' => 'checkstatus[]',
            'values' => $options,
            'checked' => $optionselected,
            'disabled' => $options,
            'readonly'=>true
            )
        );
```